# How to pull text from webpage from paragraph element in specific header inside a div using Beautifulsoup-python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Basically the title. I am trying to pull the paragraph text from the area underneath "genecards summary for name_of_gene gene" from https://www.genecards.org/cgi-bin/carddisp.pl?gene=IL6&keywords=il6 using the IL-6 gene as an example. what I want to pull is would like to pull just "IL6 (Interleukin 6) is a Protein Coding gene. Diseases associated with IL6 include Kaposi Sarcoma and Rheumatoid Arthritis, Systemic Juvenile. Among its related pathways are IL-1 Family Signaling Pathways and Immune response IFN alpha/beta signaling pathway. Gene Ontology (GO) annotations related to this gene include signaling receptor binding and growth factor activity."

I have been trying to use Beautifulsoup 4 with python. The issue I am having specifically is that I just don't know how to specify what text I want to pull from the website.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

baseURL = "https://www.genecards.org/cgi-bin/carddisp.pl?gene="
GeneToSearch = input("Gene of Interest: ")`
updatedURL = baseURL + GeneToSearch
print(updatedURL)

req = Request(updatedURL, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
response = urlopen(req).read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'lxml')

for tag in soup.find_all(['script', 'style']):
   tag.decompose()
soup.get_text(strip=True)
VALID_TAGS = ['div', 'p']

for tag in soup.findAll('GeneCards Summary for '+ GeneToSearch +    'Gene'):
    if tag.name not in VALID_TAGS:
        tag.replaceWith(tag.renderContents())

print(soup.text)
```

This just ends up giving me every element from the website.

Comment: I'm getting `HTTP Error 403: Forbidden`.

Comment: I was getting that too but don't know why I'm not anymore.. has something to do with websites recognizing the script as a bot and thus keeping it from working I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the latest version of `BeautifulSoup` you can use a pseudo css selector (:contains) to search for a tag with specific text. You can then navigate to the next `p` tag and extract corresponding text:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

baseURL = "https://www.genecards.org/cgi-bin/carddisp.pl?gene="
GeneToSearch = input("Gene of Interest: ")
updatedURL = baseURL + GeneToSearch
print(updatedURL)

req = Request(updatedURL, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
response = urlopen(req).read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'lxml')

text_find = 'GeneCards Summary for ' + GeneToSearch + ' Gene'

el = soup.select_one('h3:contains("' + text_find + '")')
summary = el.parent.find_next('p').text.strip()

print(summary)
```

Outputs:

```
IL6 (Interleukin 6) is a Protein Coding gene.
Diseases associated with IL6 include Kaposi Sarcoma and Rheumatoid Arthritis, Systemic Juvenile.
Among its related pathways are IL-1 Family Signaling Pathways and Immune response IFN alpha/beta signaling pathway.
Gene Ontology (GO) annotations related to this gene include signaling receptor binding and growth factor activity.
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. This was just the first part of what I'm trying to accomplish with the end goal being for this to parse through a column of gene names in an excel sheet and put the function in a different respective column. Will ask you for help in the future!

Answer (score 0):

Try to navigate between tags, something like this:

```
soup.select('.gc-subsection-header')[1].next_sibling.next_sibling.text
```

Ref.: [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling)